# Curl fails upload with "NSS error -5938" when called from crontab

Tags: curl, cron, openssl, ftps

I have a shell script that:

1. downloads files from a database
2. saves them as CSV files locally
3. transfers the file to another server via FTP (using curl).

When run manually, the script runs file, but when kicked off via crontab, it fails the third step. the output of CURL shows `NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)` after the STOR command (which does not occur when running manually).

Any thoughts? Some exerpts from my code/logs below:

Crontab:

```sh
    0 20 * * * cd /home/username/automation/process && ./process.sh > /home/username/automation/process/lastrun.log 2>&1
```

CURL command is run from another shell script ./totarget.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
curl -T $1 -ssl ftps://ftp.domain.com/ --user username:password --cacert /home/username/automation/process/output/team-ftp.pem -v
```

Output from CURL (paths/users/hosts replaced):

```
Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /home/username/automation/process/output/team-ftp.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: E=Team@domain.com,OU=Team Name,O=Company Name,L=City,ST=NY,C=US,CN=team.domain.com
*       start date: Aug 07 21:42:43 2019 GMT
*       expire date: Aug 06 21:42:43 2020 GMT
*       common name: team.domain.com
*       issuer: E=Team@domain.com,OU=Team Name,O=Company Name,L=City,ST=NY,C=US,CN=team.domain.com
< 220-Team Name FTP
< 220-Unauthorized use is prohibited
< 220 Access is logged
> USER username
< 331 Password required for username
> PASS password
< 230 Logged on
> PBSZ 0
< 200 PBSZ=0
> PROT P
< 200 Protection level set to P
> PWD
< 257 "/" is current directory.
* Entry path is '/'
> EPSV
* Connect data stream passively
* ftp_perform ends with SECONDARY: 0
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||61786|)
*   Trying 123.456.789.123...
* Connecting to 123.456.789.123 (123.456.789.123) port 61786
* Connected to team.domain.com (123.456.789.123) port 990 (#0)
> TYPE I
< 200 Type set to I
> STOR Filename.csv
< 150 Opening data channel for file upload to server of "/Filename.csv"
* Doing the SSL/TLS handshake on the data stream
*   CAfile: /home/username/automation/process/output/team-ftp.pem
  CApath: none
* NSS error -5938 (PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR)
* Encountered end of file
* Failure sending ABOR command: SSL connect error
* Closing connection 0
```

I exported the site's self-signed cert and put it in team-ftp.pem, which is explicitly included in case the totarget.sh script. Could really use some insight as to why this runs for me, but not for the same user's crontab.

Some system info:

```sh
$ uname -a
Linux hostname.domain.com 3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 27 05:39:05 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ curl --version
curl 7.44.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.44.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2g
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: IPv6 Largefile GSS-API Kerberos SPNEGO NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by calling bash directly from crontab and then passing the shell script to it as such:

```
 0 20 * * * bash -c "cd /home/username/automation/process && ./process.sh > /home/username/automation/process/lastrun.log 2>&1"
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future.